# Scala types - why are they not the same?

Tags: scala

```
type Some = (WarpableStats with WarpableCompanion[A]) forSome { type A <: Warpable }
type Of[A <: Warpable] = WarpableStats with WarpableCompanion[A]
```

why Of[_] is not same thing as Some ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `Of[_]` does not conform type parameter bounds. You should annotate wildcard explicitly.

`implicitly[Of[_ <: Warpable] =:= Some]` get compiles.

Why? Because [scala spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#existential-types) does not specify type constructor's constraints if the type constructor is in an existential type, more exactly, the left part of `forSome`. In your case, it's `Of`. Keep in mind that `Of[_]` is a type as whole, not `Of`.

You can see the **simplification** rule section, that simplification is done solely on `TypeDecl` part, the right part of `forSome`, and type constructors' variance notation.

In your case, the [conformance test](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#conformance) is done on existential type, `Of[_]`, not the type constructor `Of`. According the spec, `Of[_]`'s *equivalent form* is `Of[Any]` because `Of[_]` is equivalent to to `Of[T] forSome {type T >: Nothing <: Any}`, and `Of` is invariant. So it does not conform to `Some`. (By saying `equivalent form` I mean [skomelization](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#existential-types).)

Intuitively, scala compiler does not check constraints you defined in type constructor when it comes to existential type. When using existential type, you are telling scala:  **"There will exist some type that make the left hand side of `forSome` work, so don't bother to check left hand side, for now."**

Comment: But the same restriction is defined in the declaration. Why do I need to redeclare it?

Comment: @arturaz I updated the answer. Also, you can refer to this thread http://scala-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Type-Boundary-quot-Stickyness-quot-on-Wildcards-td3017503.html